# AlarmManager in background

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have a list of alarms, I put the first and when it sounds the alarm I put the next.... 
This's works. 
But if the application is in background enough time, the alarms don't work.

I put in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".Alertas_Broadcast" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.pack.pack.Alertas" />

            <category android:name="com.pack.pack" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And the broadcast and the function that put the new alarm:

```
public class Alertas_Broadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    String mensaje = "";
    if (extras != null)
      mensaje = extras.getString("mensaje");

    if (!mensaje.equals("")){
      Utilidades.generateNotification(context, mensaje, Main.class, null);
      // I put the next alarm calling setNextAlarm with the new parameters
    }
}
}

public void setNextAlarm (long milisegundos, String mensaje){
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("mensaje", mensaje);
    Intent i = new Intent("com.pack.pack.Alertas");
    i.putExtras(extras);

    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(InfoApp.miContexto, (int) milisegundos, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)InfoApp.miContexto.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    if (milisegundos != 0){
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, milisegundos, 99999999, pintent);  
    }
    else{
        alarm.cancel(pintent);
    }
}
```

Where is the problem? I imagine the problem is the action of the receiver, but I don't know how resolve it. 
I read that is not a good idea to have a service listening all the time beacause many resources are spent.

Sorry for my english and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your Activity has been in the background long enough it may have been killed by the system. You can try using a Service and setForeground() to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting the next alarm? If you are doing it through a service, you need to acquire a wakelock.

When the phone is in a sleep state and you receive an alarm, the phone will only stay awake while the BroadcastReceiver is in the onReceive() method, after which it falls asleep again. So there is no guarantee that your "setNextAlarm" is called.

Comment: I search the next date in the database and I call setNextAlarm with the new parameters. I have too the WAKE_LOCK permission in the manifest but I don't have any service